# How to make scrollbar visible around a Canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, scrollbar

I have a list of items, which I display on a Canvas. I display those items vertically, the next below the previous, just like in ListBox or ListView.

Because I need to be able to drag those items around and for that purpose I have to use a Canvas, since Canvas allows me to set concrete positions for the items.

There are many items in the collection reaching outside the boundaries of the window when displayed and for that I need to use a ScrollViewer. The problem here is that if I don't set the Canvas's height, then the ScrollViewer isn't visible.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="500" /> // Can't set Height here
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**What could I do to make the vertical scroll bar around canvas visible?**

Comment: Set the Height of the ItemsControl, not the Canvas. Your problem is that a Canvas doesn't expand to accommodate its content. You need to have the viewmodel (or something) calculate the needed width and height, and bind them to ItemsControl.Width and ItemsControl.Height.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you for your response, I did exactly as you said, It works of course. :-) I will post the resulting solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on @EdPlunkett's answer I came up with this solution:

I added bindings to MinHeight and MinWidth of the ItemsControl (altought the normal Height and Width would work as well I suppose).

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AlbumItems}" 
                  MinHeight="{Binding EditorHeight}" 
                  MinWidth="{Binding EditorWidth}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and in my data context I call this method to calculate the size and set the EditorHeight and EditorWidth properties to their calculated values.

```
    private void calculateEditorSize()
    {
        int maxEditorHeight = AlbumItems.Max((component) => component.Top + component.Height);
        int maxEditorWidth = AlbumItems.Max((component) => component.Left + component.Width);

        EditorHeight = maxEditorHeight;
        EditorWidth = maxEditorWidth;
    }
```